# Put the index first with each_with_index

Tags: ruby

I am using Array() with each_with_index to output a array with index but I want it to output

```
[[0,obj1],[1,obj2]....]
```

whereas each_with_index makes it output

```
[[obj1,0],[obj2,1]....]
```

Is there anyway this can be fixed easilly?

As been asked to show code.

```
Array(test.each_with_index)
```

Comment: @Sergio I pretty much said what was doing, was basic ruby of Array(array.each_with_index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `.map { |x| x.reverse }` after the `each_with_index`.

Comment: Thankyou , however all that does is return the objects reversed         
    
    `irb(main):001:0> test=["poppy","kitty","puppy"]
    => ["poppy", "kitty", "puppy"]
    irb(main):002:0> Array(test.each_with_index.map{|x| x.reverse})
    => ["yppop", "yttik", "yppup"]`

Comment: You need to run this on the array -- `["foo", "bar"].each_with_index.to_a.map {|x| x.reverse } => [[0, "foo"], [1, "bar"]]`.

Comment: It works here: `Array(%w(a b c).each_with_index.map &:reverse).inspect` returns `[[0, "a"], [1, "b"], [2, "c"]]`.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira May I ask what makes that better?

Comment: @nekosune, `&:reverse` is pretty much the same as `proc { |receiver| receiver.reverse }`, just shorter and more elegant, in my opinion. It's functionally equivalent to your example above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
[obj1, obj2, ..., objN].map.with_index{|a,i| [i,a] }
#=> [[0, obj1], [1, obj2], ..., [N-1, objN]]
```

Comment: Kind of exactly what I didnt want